# Download public group messages without authentiction - Telethon

Tags: python, download, bots, telegram, telethon

Is there, at the moment, any way to download messages from a public group without phone authentication? While using a bot, I get an error:

> Exception has occurred: BotMethodInvalidError
> The API access for bot users is restricted. The method you tried to invoke cannot be executed as a bot (caused by GetHistoryRequest)

I'd like to automate the process of getting new messages so I'm not able to authenticate every time the session starts.

Is there any workaround?

Answer (score 0):

The bot can't get the message history. Bots work with updates. You can receive new messages while your bot is connected

```
@bot.on(events.NewMessage)
async def echo_all(event):
    print(event.message)
```